# Al compilar programa en C dice que hay un parásito en el programa

Tags: c, enum

El programa que quiero compilar es :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define USR_MSG_H "Hola"
#define USR_MSG_C "Chau"

typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} bool_t;

int main(void)
{
   bool_t saludo = TRUE;

   if(saludo == TRUE)
   {
      printf("%s\n",USR_MSG_H);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("%s\n",USR_MSG_C);
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Al compilar aparece :

```
error : '\342' parásito en el programa
error : '\200' parásito en el programa
error : '\217' parásito en el programa
```

Por qué puede ocurrir esto ? Desde ya , gracias.

Comment: El programa me compila bien y sin errores.  Que sistema operativo y editor de texto estas utilizando?

Comment: puede ser que haya un caracter utf-8, http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=342+200+217&mode=obytes

Comment: http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/200F.html right to left mark, es invisible ( se te mete al copiar y pegar directamente desde una página en hebreo, árabe o persa ) prueba copiando y pegando con shift o si tenes una opción de "pegar sin formato"

Comment: El SO es Linux Mint y el editor es bluefish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error parece que es "[*Stray character in program*](https://www.bing.com/search?q=stray+character+in+program)", se da habitualmente al copiapegar código desde una página web o desde un origen con codificación diferente. Cualquiera de estas opciones puede solucionar tu problema:

- Copia el código a mano.
- Antes de pegar en el entorno de desarrollo, pega el código en un block de notas.
- Busca la posición de los caracteres incorrectos y borralos manualmente.